# Carousel with Bootstrap 3 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Ok I seem to be having a problem here. I can't get my carousel to work. I've made sure I'm loading all the javascript files and even added Google's cdn link to be sure. I also believe I am calling it correctly. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Church of the Hills | Nashville TN</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Google Web Font -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
    <link href="css/landing-page.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

    <div class="dark-content-section">
        <!-- /.container -->
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">     </li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="img/girls-slide.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                ...
              </div>
              <img src="img/girls-slide.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                ...
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.dark-content-section -->

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
          $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel();
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are calling the jQuery library two times. You need to load it only once.

Comment: Please checkout a complete Carousel with all the options http://jsbin.com/ragojiye/8/ and use what you see fit for your use case.

Comment: Even when I'm calling it once it doesn't work. I put the cdn link first just in case the other wasn't loading properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to have one

```
   <div class="item"> ... </div>
```

per image and in your code you only have one, yet you have 3 li's as indicators.

Comment: That's it. I was copying and pasting but didn't go far enough out and missed the div item. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#555/text:First slide" alt="First slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzc3NyI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojNTU1O2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+Rmlyc3Qgc2xpZGU8L3RleHQ+PC9zdmc+">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#444/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzY2NiI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojNDQ0O2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+U2Vjb25kIHNsaWRlPC90ZXh0Pjwvc3ZnPg==">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#333/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzU1NSI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMzMzO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+VGhpcmQgc2xpZGU8L3RleHQ+PC9zdmc+">
    </div>
</div>
```